# Migrate android Project to Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, migrate

When I import a downloaded project, I get this message:

> Migrate Project to Gradle?
> This project does not use the Gradle build system. We recommend that you migrate to using the Gradle build system.
>
> More Information about migrating to Gradle
>
> Don't show this message again.

How to make the android project using gradle build system?

Comment: Did you try to import the project into AndroidStudio?
If so, just follow the instructions

Comment: You can Click on "Yes"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to the Welcome Screen of Android Studio (If you are in a project: File->Close Project).
There is a button "Import project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc.)", press it.
From here on out, the wizard will guide you, but I'll describe them here too:

Select your project folder.
Enter your new project path.
Check all boxes.

There are many guides for migrating to Android Studio out there (for example [by Google themselves](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html)).